# How to split a string after a date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the string `"11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break"` and would like to cut both dates from it and only retrieve both dates (`11/21/2018`) and (`11/27/2018`) as well as the title in some form of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split` method.

```js
    let str = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break"
    let endOfFirstDate = str.indexOf(" ")
    let firstDate = str.substring(0, endOfFirstDate).trim()
    let endOfSecondDate = str.indexOf(" ", endOfFirstDate + 1)
    let secondDate = str.substring(endOfFirstDate, endOfSecondDate).trim()
    let title = str.substring(endOfSecondDate, str.length).trim()
```

Comment: It was three values in an array, you could assign them to new variables. However I did that in editing.

Comment: This question is edited 3 times. My answer is related to first edition of question. In that edition, you wanted all three values separated. So ok, forget it!

Answer (score 2):

You can match the dates and everything else while replacing groups like this:

```js
const str = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break";
const ans = [];

str.replace(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) |(.+$)/g, (_, date, text) => {
    ans.push(date || text);
});

console.log(ans);
```

You can see how the regex groups matches here: https://regex101.com/r/IXW6Hv/1

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly done using Regular expressions:

```js
const text = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break";

console.log(text.match(/([0-9\/]+\s){2}(.+)/)[2])
```

A more basic way is to split the string into words, remove the first two, then join it again:

```js
const text = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break";

console.log(text.split(" ").splice(2).join(" "))
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great in the scenario I was using it for.

Answer (score 0):

if your date is always dd/mm/yyyy style, you can try this one to test it.

```js
let str = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break"
let tmp = str;
tmp = tmp.replace(/[\d]+\/[\d]+\/[\d]+/g," ")
let arr = tmp.split(" ");
for(const item of arr){
 if(item){
  str = str.replace(item," ");
 }
}
for(const item of str.split(" ")){
 if(item){
  console.log(item);
 }
}
```

if all your data are separate by space, you can try a simple one like below:

```js
let str = "11/21/2018 11/27/2018 Thanksgiving Break"
let arr = str.split(" ");
for(const item of arr){
 if(/[\d]+\/[\d]+\/[\d]+/.test(item)){
  console.log(item);
 }
}
```